# put pipe to stdin another process

Tags: fork, pipe, stdin

I'm using pipe to send an array of numbers to another process to sort them. So far, I'm able to get the result from another process using fdopen. However, I can't figure out how to send data from the pipe as stdin for another process.

Here is my code:

        `int main ()
        {
            int fd[2], i, val;
            pid_t child;
            char file[10];
            FILE *f;`

```
        pipe(fd);

        child = fork();
        if (child == 0)
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
            execl("sort", "sort", NULL);

        }
        else
        {
            close(fd[0]);
            printf ("BEFORE\n");
            for (i = 100; i < 110; i++)
            {
                write(fd[1], &i, sizeof (int));
                printf ("%d\n", i);
            }
            close(fd[1]);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
```

By the way, how can the other process get input? scanf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your pipe is set up correctly. The problems may start at `execl()`. For this call you should specify an absolute path, which is probably `/bin/sort` if you mean the Unix utility. There is also a version of the call `execlp()` which searches automatically on the PATH.

The next problem is that `sort` is text based, more specifically line based, and you're sending binary garbage to its STDIN.

In the parent process you should write formatted text into the pipe.

```
FILE *wpipe = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
for (i = 100; i < 110; i++) {
    fprintf(wpipe, "%d\n", i);
    ...
}
fclose(wpipe);
```

A reverse loop from 110 down to 100 may test your sorting a bit better.

Comment: I'm writing the sort myself, but thanks to you, I realize it's text based; therefore, when I change everything to string, it works perfectly :)